# Can I add a link to my test methods that opens the method under test (intellij and junit, and spring)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

myuch like I could add a 
`//todo` or link to an issue `//myIssue-ID`

I want to have something like the below, which is clickable and opens up the relevant source

```
//link com.stack.myClass.myMethod()
public void testMyMethod(){
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by using Javadoc comments with `@see` doclet annotation:

`MyClass.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow;

/**
 * @author maba, 2013-09-09
 */
public class MyClass {
    public void myMethod() {
    }
}
```

`MyTestClass.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * @author maba, 2013-09-09
 */
public class MyTestClass {

    @Test
    /**
     * @see com.stackoverflow.MyClass#myMethod
     */
    public void testMyMethod() {
    }
}
```

Now you can click on the link after the `#` sign:

[image]

---

An alternative is to use `{@link}`:

```
/**
 * {@link com.stackoverflow.MyClass#myMethod}
 */
```